# Android compass example

Tags: android, compass-geolocation

I'm searching for a compass example for Android. All I need to do is to get the correct bearing (in portrait & landscape mode).

I already found several samples, some use only `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION`, some use a combination of `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` & `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`.

Which is the correct & common way to get the bearing for let's say Android 1.6 - 4.0?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` is deprecated.

The documentation says you should use `SensorManager.getOrientation()` instead.

So you should read from `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` as well as from `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`, and then call `SensorManager.getRotationMatrix()` and finally `SensorManager.getOrientation()` which will return you the orientation of the phone.

From there if you see this diagram it is trivial to get the phone's orientation. This is probably what your second example does, but I don't know because you didn't show me what it is.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to attach the example: http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/01/using-orientation-sensors-simple.html   So this one is the correct way?

Comment: Obviously how you use the data is up to you, `onSensorChanged` is where the interesting math is.

Comment: One more question: How do i get the correct bearing in degrees out of the "azimut = orientation[0];" line?

Comment: @nr1 Math.toDegrees(orientation[0])

Answer (score 5):

**Thanks to Dan** for his sample code.

But there is just a **little correction** : change `event.values` to `event.values.clone()` according to this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/UNMaDEUcXb0).
It works for me now after this modification.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` and `SensorManager.getOrientation()` method doesn't give me precise values. The deprecated method `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` works well. :)

Comment: Fix your code then. The code sample seems to be working fine (http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/01/using-orientation-sensors-simple.html paired with gezdy's comment)

Comment: Or maybe you need to recalibrate your device