# android - Can we get the compass direction without a physical compass (e.g. using 2 GPS points ? )

Tags: android, gps, compass-geolocation

my phone has no compass, can I get a compass-like direction (angle) without a physical compass (e.g. using 2 GPS points for moving pobject ? ) or any other method ?

Comment: Here is an example for what you're asking for. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734190/android-compass-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Location.getBearing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing%28%29) to get bearing from location object obtained using LocationManager.

Also you can calculate it manually using [Location.bearingTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29) method.

[Android SDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/location/Location.java#Location.computeDistanceAndBearing%28double,double,double,double,float%5B%5D%29) using [precise method](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf) to operate with locations. The method considers that the earth isn't flat.

Comment: Can I depend on this in matter of accuracy? I mean can I ignore the compass completely ? I only need the direction in travelling mode.

Comment: @drdigital If you have to know direction of travel - use this. Compass provides orientation of the device. The difference is when you are going backwards: device has an azimuth opposite to the direction of travel.

Answer (score 1):

If the device is moving then capturing multiple GPS locations can be used to get the direction of travel.

Note though that this will only give you the direction of travel, not the orientation of the device.

EDIT: If you have two points direction between those points is simple mathematics, which you can find on any number of websites.  I also believe android/iOS etc have some of these functions built in to make things easier.

Comment: If the points are formatted as such - (X, Y) (X, Y) then the simple math would be the square root of (X₂ - X₁)squared + (Y₂ - Y₁)squared see http://www.mathopenref.com/coorddist.html

Comment: @SquiresSquire the earth is an ellipsoid. More precise way to calculate it http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf