# How to rotate markers using sensor manager in google maps android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-sensors

In my project I should rotate the marker on a google map same as the compass functionality in android ,my doubt is should I use an imageview or can I rotate the marker directly.Help me out guys if any mistakes please don't mind I'm a newbie.

Comment: can anybody give me an example code rather than downing my question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the marker directly using this

[Animate the rotation of the Marker in google map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967821/animate-the-rotation-of-the-marker-in-google-map-v2)

In sensor manager use this :

[Android: Problems calculating the Orientation of the Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740808/android-problems-calculating-the-orientation-of-the-device)

Comment: thank you very much , your post help me a lot . I solved my problem and finished marker rotation using sensor manager.

Comment: Please accep my answer. Thanks :)